# Moving my app on NEAR to Solana

Tags: rust, build-bpf

I have an application in NEAR (developed with smart contracts in Rust). Is there any way that I can deploy it in Solana without having to create everything from scratch? Because both use Rust as the base language for smart contracts, I hope there is a way to achieve this.

PS: My goal is to expand my user base.
PS: For example, Aurora allows Ethereum developers to build apps over NEAR. Is there a similar alternativative for NEAR developers to create apps on Solana?

Comment: The programming model on Solana is very different compared to NEAR, so I don't think it'll be possible to do easily.